# C++ app doesn't build in VS Code but build in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, build

I can't get the С++ desktop program to build in vs code.
I've set up VS code as described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_check-your-microsoft-visual-c-installation

For simple "helloworld" app everything works fine.
But for bellow Desktop application code doesn't build in VS Code (but it builds in Visual Studio 2022):

hello.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        DrawTextW(hdc, L"Hi", -1, &rect, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    WNDCLASSW wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandleW(nullptr);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"HelloWindowClass";
    RegisterClassW(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowW(
        L"HelloWindowClass",
        L"hi",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        400,
        300,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        GetModuleHandleW(nullptr),
        nullptr
    );

    if (hwnd == nullptr)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my `.vscode\tasks.json`:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/nologo",
                "/Fe${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Here is output in terminal (VS code):

```
 *  Executing task: C/C++: cl.exe build active file 

Starting build...
cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /nologo /FeC:\Dev\learncpp\testwin\hello.exe C:\Dev\learncpp\testwin\hello.cpp
hello.cpp
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetMessageA@16 referenced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__TranslateMessage@4 referenced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DispatchMessageA@4 referenced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DefWindowProcA@16 referenced in function "long __stdcall WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PostQuitMessage@4 referenced in function "long __stdcall WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegisterClassW@4 referenced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CreateWindowExW@48 referenced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ShowWindow@8 referenced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DrawTextW@20 referenced in function "long __stdcall WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__UpdateWindow@4 referenced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__BeginPaint@8 referenced in function "long __stdcall WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__EndPaint@8 referenced in function "long __stdcall WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetClientRect@8 referenced in function "long __stdcall WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
C:\Dev\learncpp\testwin\hello.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 13 unresolved externals

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

How can I setup VS Code so it could also build this c++ program?

P.S. I've just started learning C++, but I'm VS code user (webdev, python), so want to use VS Code for C++ too.

Comment: My advice when this happens again is to Google the function listed in the unresolved reference. For example I Googled `GetMessageA` which took me to [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagea#requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagea#requirements) which tells you the exact name of the library to add in the Requirements section of the msdn documentation. This is basically how I have done this for the 30 or so years I have written c++ code on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Holly guacamole, ChatGPT answered my question:

> It looks like the issue is related to unresolved external symbols,
> which means the linker cannot find the implementations for the
> functions used in your code. This typically happens when you are using
> functions from external libraries, and the linker doesn't know where
> to find them.
>
> In your case, the functions like GetMessage, TranslateMessage,
> DispatchMessage, etc., are part of the Windows API, and you need to
> link against the appropriate library.
>
> You can add the necessary library to your tasks.json file. Modify the
> "args" section of your tasks.json as follows:

```
"args": [
    "/Zi",
    "/EHsc",
    "/nologo",
    "/Fe${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
    "${file}",
    "user32.lib"  // Add this line to link against the user32 library
],
```